# How to test a Django class-based view receives correct arguments?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-class-based-views

I can't work out how to test that a Django class-based view receives the expected `kwargs` from a URL pattern.

If I have my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(
        regex=r"^people/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",
        view=views.PersonDetailView.as_view(),
        name='person_detail'
    ),
]
```

And my `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from myapp.models import Person

class PersonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Person
```

I can test that a request to the URL calls the correct view like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import resolve
from myapp import views
from myapp.factories import PersonFactory

class UrlsTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_person_detail_view(self):
        PersonFactory(pk=3)
        self.assertEqual(resolve('/people/3/').func.__name__,
                         views.PersonDetailView.__name__)
```

But I'd also like to test that a request to `/people/3/` results in `{'pk': '3'}` being passed to `PersonDetailView`, and I can't work out where in a class-based view receives the `kwargs` in order to test it (by patching the receiving method, I guess).

Comment: When the view runs, it calls `dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)` You could patch the `dispatch` method and check `kwargs['pk']`. You can see how the `as_view()` method returns a callable view [in the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8346680e1ca4a8ddc8190baf3f5f944f6418d5cf/django/views/generic/base.py#L47).

Comment: Do you need to test it? :p Django has tests for url parsing of regex's correctly.  You could indirectly verify this by sending a request through a url using django's test client, as part of another test.  Does it need an explicit test?

Comment: Hmm, maybe not dm03514... there seem to be so many ways to test, or not test, Django URLs and views...

Comment: @Alasdair: Thanks. Would there be a way to do this without using Django's builtin test client? Or is that necessary in this case?

Comment: The test client seems like the best way to test this, it's not clear why you don't want to use it.

Comment: Just because I've been replacing some URL/view tests that previously used the test client with alternatives that are more narrowly focused (like using `RequestFactory`. But maybe a test that tests a particular URL sends the correct data to a particular view would require the test client.

Comment: If you use `RequestFactory` you are testing that the view returns the correct response for a given request. You are not testing that the url for the view is correctly configured.

Comment: Yes, I'm not suggesting I use `RequestFactory` in this instance, just an example of a different test in which I'm not using the test client. Sorry, obviously not explaining myself well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I checked the id or pk on my views (I'm using Django1.11):

```
from menus.models import Item
from menus.views import ItemListView
from django.test import RequestFactory
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


person = User.objects.get(username='ryan')
factory = RequestFactory()

request = factory.get('/items/')
request.user = person

response = ItemListView.as_view()(request)

#prints the id or pk of the requesting user
response._request.user.pk
response._request.user.id
```

Comment: [example in django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/advanced/#example)